# I can't remove a child in javascript that is pretty much identical to another child that i can remove

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, removechild

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  
<body>
  <div id="box">
  <button id="start" type="button" onclick="myStart()" > Start</button>
 
<script>
  function myStart() {
    document.getElementById("start").style.display="none";
    
    var rosso = casuale(0,1);
    if (rosso==0) {
    var imgtest1= document.createElement("input");
 imgtest1.src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif";
 imgtest1.type="image";
 imgtest1.style.height="50px";
 imgtest1.style.width="50px";
 imgtest1.style.position="absolute";
 imgtest1.style.top="300px";
 imgtest1.style.left="0px";
 imgtest1.onclick= function() { document.getElementById("box").removeChild(imgtest1)
        }
     document.getElementById("box").appendChild(imgtest1);
 }
 else {
 var imgtest1= document.createElement("input");
 imgtest1.src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/impressivewebs/2014-02/w3schools-logo.jpg";
 imgtest1.type="image";
 imgtest1.style.height="50px";
 imgtest1.style.width="50px";
 imgtest1.style.position="absolute";
 imgtest1.style.top="300px";
 imgtest1.style.left="0px";
 imgtest1.onclick= function() { document.getElementById("box").removeChild(imgtest1)}
 document.getElementById("box").appendChild(imgtest1);
 }
    }
    
function casuale(min, max) { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); 
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

I have a little problem with this code:

```
var rosso = casuale(0, 3)
if (rosso == 0) {
  var imgtest1 = document.createElement("input");
  imgtest1.src = "graphic/badtarget.png";
  imgtest1.type = "image";
  imgtest1.style.height = "50px";
  imgtest1.style.width = "50px";
  imgtest1.style.position = "absolute";
  imgtest1.style.top = "300px";
  imgtest1.style.left = "0px";
  imgtest1.onclick = function() {
    error++;
    checkerror();
  }

  document.getElementById("box").appendChild(imgtest1);

} else {
  var imgtest1 = document.createElement("input");
  imgtest1.src = "graphic/goodtarget.png";
  imgtest1.type = "image";
  imgtest1.style.height = "50px";
  imgtest1.style.width = "50px";
  imgtest1.style.position = "absolute";
  imgtest1.style.top = "300px";
  imgtest1.style.left = "0px";
  imgtest1.onclick = function() {
    point++;
    document.getElementById("box").removeChild(imgtest1);
    if (point == maxp) {
      livello2(7);
      cleartarget();
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("box").appendChild(imgtest1);
}
```

wheni try to remove the child "imgtest1" with the goodtarget.png image i have no problems, instead when i want to remove the child with the badtarget.png image the button stay here and there is no way to remove it. Why this happens? there is a way to solve this? if needed i can post other lines of code.
Thanks

Edit: Sorry for wasting your time, in the snippet the code works as intended (both the green and the blue images can disappear) but in my program can not.
the lines of code that i use for the remove child is a function that should be called at the end of a level:

```
 var myNode = document.getElementById("box");
 while (myNode.firstChild) {
 myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
 }
```

this function cant remove the objects created with the "imgtest1.src = "graphic/badtarget.png";"
Thanks for your time

Comment: You'll need to do a [mcve], we can't tell what's going wrong from the above. We can speculate (my guess is you're overwriting the value of `imgtest1` after adding an element but not removing it), but speculation is a waste of everyone's time, including yours. (When doing the MCVE, please use Stack Snippets -- the `<>` toolbar button -- to make a **runnable** demo on-site.)

Comment: where are you defining casuale? and +1 ----^

Comment: um, there is no line in the first one that removes it like the second one...

Comment: What did you expect? The event handler only does `removeChild` in the case of the good image.